# Why does the Mobile Safari Browser on iOS not allow file uploads?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

As already known, it's not possible for iOS users to select image files to upload from Safari on iPhone, because the browse button to display the "select file"- dialog is disabled. It works fine on Android, but not on iPhone...

What is the particular reason for that issue? 
I heard that the browse button is disabled because there isn't a file browser on the iPhone. Someone other said that Safari just disabled root access. Is there any reliable source which explains the issue? (I need it for my thesis.)

Comment: You can't access the file system under iOS, an upload function doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, so the access is denied? Or does iOS not work with a file system?

Comment: @patrix it does make sense: apps have it, so why can't safari get photo upload? besides, ios6 got support for that anyways. :)

Comment: Photos are special (there is an access API for them), for the rest see Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS apps can only read data in their own directory and thus only Safari would be able to use these files - so how could you create them and put them in Safari's directories?

From [Apple's Filesystem basics development documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2)

> An iOS app’s interactions with the file system are limited mostly to
>   the directories inside the app’s sandbox. During installation of a new
>   app, the installer code creates a home directory for the app, places
>   the app in that directory, and creates several other key directories.
>   These directories constitute the app’s primary view of the file
>   system. Figure 1-1 shows a representation of the sandbox for an app.
>
> Figure 1-1  Each iOS app operates within its own sandbox
>
> Because it is in a sandbox, an app is generally prohibited from
>   accessing or creating files in directories outside of its home
>   directory. One exception to this rule occurs when an app uses public
>   system interfaces to access things such as the user’s contacts or
>   music. In those cases, the system frameworks handle any file-related
>   operations needed to read from or modify the appropriate data store

Comment: I'd like to add that starting with iOS 6, Mobile Safari will allow file inputs for uploading photos and videos from your Photo Library.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 6 fixed this problem *by granting one exception* to the sand boxing of apps from each-other's data. Upload buttons may now ask about taking/browsing for a picture or video clip to upload.

Other than by exception, there still is no full filesystem access on iOS 6 and lower.

Answer (score 3):

From all of my research I cannot find a descriptive answers as to why this feature has been disabled in mobile safari. I don't know if you are interested but if you have your iOS device jailbroken there is a tweak called "[Safari Upload Enabler](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/08/jailbreak-only-safari-upload-enabler-upload-files-from-within-mobile-safari)" which gives mobile safari the ability to upload files. You can buy it on cydia for $1.99

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also thanks for the link, I'll have a look. I asked because I'm performing usability engineering in my thesis and wanted to explain why I have to make the website into a native app.

Comment: Basically unlocking removes some security and so apps have access to the whole file system.